# Finding extremas of a function

Tags: partial-derivative, 3d

$f(x,y) = xe^{-{x^3}+{y^3}}$ and

I am to find extrema values of that 2-variable function.

I come up with the point $P(3^{1/3},0,f(3^{1/3},0))$ is its only critical point.

I tried to apply second derivative test it is inconclusive.

Then, is there anything to do from this step on ?

Comment: I think it neither has maxima nor minima because if you draw a disk around critical point. As $e^{-(x^3 + y^3)}$ is always positive, so it all depends on x. and x takes negative values in 2nd and 4th quadrant while positive in others.

Comment: According to my calculation, the critical point is at $x=3^{-1/3}$ and $y=0$.